# One month timer circuit

Tags: relay, timer, control

I need to cut a signal wire after one month from it start working.
So I am looking for timer circuit that it work by small battery make a short circuit for my signal wire after around ( few days more less ) one month.

Answer (score 3):

Even the tiny and cheap PIC 10F200 can do this.  It comes with a built-in 4 MHz oscillator, which means 1 MHz instruction clock, which you can divide down in firmware to get any length delay you want.

The easiest on this part is to use the timer wrapping as the base event for your clock.  This is a 8 bit timer, so that would be every 256 instruction cycles, or every 256 µs.  The firmware spins in a loop waiting for the high bit of the timer to change from 1 to 0.  It then runs the code to process one more clock tick, waits for the high bit to become 1, then goes back to the top of the loop.  You can easily do all the clock tick processing in 256 instructions.

You want to delay about 30 day, which is 2.6 Ms.  at 256 µs/tick, you need to wait 10.1 GTicks, or 2<sup>33.2</sup> ticks.  You therefore need at least a 34 bit counter.  Since it's easier to use whole bytes, use 5 bytes for your counter.

Initialize the counter to the value for 30 days on startup, then decrement it by one every clock tick.  You then check it for being 0, and activate your switch when it is.

Comment: You could use the Timer0 prescaler in OPTION register for a divider up to 1:256. This slows down the timer tick from 0.256ms to 65.536ms. This also removes 8-bits from the required ticks size, so you can use standard 32-bit integers (if the PIC10F supports them) in code for the period.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't remember exactly what prescaler options are available, but what you say is fine since you won't be resetting the timer.  As for a "standard" integer size, this machine has no such thing other than 8 bits.  You can string as many 8-bit bytes as you have RAM for to make a wide word.  This sort of thing only matters if you're using a compiler, which is kindof silly for a 10F200.

Comment: I see - I can understand it's kind of "silly" for such a small device, yet also quite convenient if you're fluent in C and not in assembler.. That's why I was thinking about 32-bit integers. Under the hood it seems the compiler will generate comparable instructions to the approach you described.

Answer (score 3):

A microcontroller would be easiest. Even the internal clock of most micros (usually 1%-ish) is good enough to easily meet your +/-10% tolerance. When you write the code you will want to create a very simple code structure that can be mostly bypassed for testing, because waiting 30 days or more for each test result is probably not desirable. For example if you use C and an unsigned int for the total time, you might use 43200 as the comparison for your counter, then you just have to make a 60 second timer and verify that it works, and the system works  for n=1 and 2, (and independently test the counter to 43200, but at a much higher frequency). Also make sure that whatever should happen *after* the elapsed time and switching actually works, and it doesn't (say) restart the output after some delay.

A month is short enough that you don't need to take heroic measures to reduce supply current to get a reasonable battery to last, but check that, of course. For really long battery life- low current consumption- it's better to clock the chip at a low frequency such as 32kHz, but that's not necessary here.

For the signal control, if you can't use a transistor such as a MOSFET, a latching relay can be used to handle a wide range of signal voltages and frequencies and currents. Because of the latching characteristic they require current only when switched so they are suitable for battery operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a micro-controller board. There are plenty to choose from for hobbyists. One of the most popular is the Arduino.

- Write some code to generate a 1 s delay and switch the output. Test it.
- Add some code to count 60 s to make a 1 minute delay. Test it.
- Add some code to count 60 minutes to make a 1 h delay. Test it.
- Add some code to count 24 of those to make a 1 day delay. Test it.
- Add some code to make an *n*-day delay. Test it.

Add some code on each step to print the elapsed time to the serial port so you can monitor progress.

Done.

Comment: I sense the making of a 30 day blocking function...

Comment: The solution depends on the accuracy required, delay() has some error which will accumulate with time.

Comment: Now where did I mention using the delay() function? :^)

Comment: @transistor, you proposed for OP to write it.

Comment: I meant delay <without brackets>, regardless of what function you are using. Generally delaying is based on NOP's which is based on the crystal oscillation or the internal RC oscillator, and both of these are very far from ideal clocks. I don't think this deserved a downvote though as the OP certainly doesn't require accuracy, so I'll compensate with a +1. Please make sure you make a note that you may only achieve 1 month +/- Error. Estimating that error would make your answer much more valuable.

Comment: I've never had to make long-term stability calculations for my projects. I'll leave that aspect for someone else, I'm afraid, due to time constraints. Thanks for the feedback.